# Selecting and counting each iteration with PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, iteration

I am trying to SELECT all the distinct values from my table and count the number of iterations per value.

I am using this:

```
$ordered = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(itemId) as countId, itemId FROM ordered_items GROUP BY itemId");
    $ordered->execute();
while($orderedItems == $ordered->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
echo $orderedItems['itemId']." and ".$orderedItems['countId'];
        }
```

It comes out blank.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have a syntax error, you are using two equal like it is a comparison, instead you are assign to `$orderedItems` you fetched array

```
while($orderedItems == $ordered->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                  //^you should use only one equal
```

Just change to

```
while($orderedItems = $ordered->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```